# Should I release the NSError object of NSFileManager's copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, memory-management

NSFileManager has a method to do copying.

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
```

If an error occurs, the third parameter **(NSError **)** upon return will contain an NSError object describing the problem.

**Question: do I need to release it?**

There are some other methods, for example this one takes **(NSString **)**,

```
NSPropertyListSerialization +(NSData *)dataFromPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format errorDescription:(NSString **)errorString
```

do they follow the same memory management rules? To release or not to, that's the question.

---Answer

As Anders said, the answer is "not" to release.

I got confused because the class NSPropertyListSerialization has a method

```
+ (NSData *)dataFromPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format errorDescription:(NSString **)errorString
```

the document says that I should release the third argument if not nil. However it's deprecated and replaced by

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithPropertyList:(id)plist format:(NSPropertyListFormat)format options:(NSPropertyListWriteOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```

and the argument is **(NSError **)** now. No need to release as other similiar methods. So the general memory manegement rule is no need to release this kind of arguments.

---Reference document

In Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), section You Don’t Own Objects Returned by Reference:

When you invoke any of these methods, you do not create the NSError object, so you do not own it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The returned NSError object is an autoreleased object so you shouldn't release it

The argument just tells the function where to put the returned error object (if any)

EDIT: can't spell today it seems

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:(NSData *) mutabilityOption:(NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions) format:(NSPropertyListFormat *) errorDescription:(NSString **)]
```

If you're working with something like this returns

```
(NSString **)
```

then you should check documentation that clearly states if you're required to release it. If documentation does not state anything about you releasing returning object like

```
- (BOOL)copyItemAtPath:(NSString *)srcPath toPath:(NSString *)dstPath error:(NSError **)error
```

then don't wory about them, they will be released when appropriate or have already been autoreleased by framework.